# When I ask ReSharper to flatten out my get, set to one line it often doesn't do them all. Anyone know why?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

Starting with this code I used ReSharper to tidy my code:

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty TestProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Test), typeof(string), typeof(BaseGrid), default(string));
    public string Test
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TestProperty);
        set => SetValue(TestProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty TapCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TapCommand), typeof(Command), typeof(BaseGrid), default(Command));
    public Command TapCommand {
        get => (Command)GetValue(TapCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(TapCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TapCommandParamProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TapCommandParam), typeof(object), typeof(BaseGrid), default(object));
    public object TapCommandParam {
        get => (object)GetValue(TapCommandParamProperty);
        set => SetValue(TapCommandParamProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(BaseGrid), default(string));
    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }
```

ReSharper move the Bindable properties to the top of the file and orders everything which I wanted. But it changes the `get, set` to look like this:

```
    public Command TapCommand{
        get => (Command) GetValue(TapCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(TapCommandProperty, value);
    }
    public object TapCommandParam{
        get => GetValue(TapCommandParamProperty);
        set => SetValue(TapCommandParamProperty, value);
    }
    public string Test{ get => (string) GetValue(TestProperty); set => SetValue(TestProperty, value); }
    public string Text{ get => (string) GetValue(TextProperty); set => SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
```

My question is, why is it that sometimes ReSharper only flatten out some of the `get, set` to one line (which is what I wanted) and doesn't do the others?

Note:

a) I am using the latest version of ReSharper, Visual Studio, .net etc.
b) Property declaration is set to: "At end of line no space)"

Has anyone else experienced the same problem?

Comment: Resulting line length over X characters? "TapCommandParamProperty" is a lot longer than "TestProperty". Make "TapCommandParamProperty" shorter and see what happens

Comment: Thanks, you solved the mystery.  I shortened the name and it worked.  Would you like to add that as an answer so we can help others with the same problem.  Also any ideas on how to change the line length minimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's the "wrap long lines" setting, possibly your property lines are going over the max line length (default 120 characters I think)

[The fine manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Enforcing_Code_Formatting_Rules.html#reformatting-with-different-line-break-styles) says the relevant option is in Alt-R,O then use the "**Right margin (columns)** preference on the **Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Line Breaks and Wrapping**"

Note , I don't use R#r so feel free to edit any inaccuracies in this answer